# Compare means of 2 variables (no individual data available)

Tags: anova, t-test, aggregation

**Short question:**

I want to find out whether the means of 2 variables differ significantly. I know how large the dataset is (N~2000), but I only have the mean scores averaged over all participants. I do not have information about standard deviation.

Is there a test that can do that?

**Details:**

2 variables x1 and x2 were measured at times t1 and t2. Both increase. I need to compare *relative* change over time. The relative change for x1 is  x1t2 / x1t1. Since the huge majority of subjects at t1 have values of 0 on my x, calculating relative increase is impossible for these (and I would lose 90% of the data). So what I do instead is averaging x1 and x2 scores over the whole population at both measurement points, and then calculate the relative increase of these mean scores.

Example: Assume the mean of x1t1 to be 0.5 and the mean of x1t2 to be 2.0. The relative increase is 4 (or 500%). Assume the relative increase of x2 to be 5 (or 600%). Now I want to test whether 4 and 5 differ from each other significantly.

Comment: Because the relative increase of the means is *not* equal to the mean of the relative increases, I wonder whether your procedure is at all meaningful for your study.  Perhaps you could settle for determining whether the *net* increases are significantly different?

Comment: Thank you. Relative increase of the means is different from means of relative increase because N in both cases are drastically different (2000 vs. 200). I cannot really calculate the mean of the relative increases, because it is infinity for 90% of the sample (increase from 0 to something). What do you mean with the _net_ increase?

Comment: "Net" increase is just the *difference* between the mean at time $t_2$ and the mean at time $t_1$.

Comment: We have to report both absolute and relative increase in the paper. The interesting thing is that the absolute increase is very heterogeneous, but the relative increase is basically the same for each item. I just need a way to run the stats on the relative increase now.

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me: earlier you stated the relative increase *did not exist* (is "infinity") for many items, because they started at zero; but now your latest comment implies that not only do these relative increases exist, but they vary only a little! What is really going on? BTW, I'm asking these questions because what you ask for is not possible with relative increases, but it *may* be possible with net increases.

Comment: All items go up a lot. The items at time1 vary drastically in their means, so do they at time2. Interestingly, the order of the means stays the same. For instance, item 1 is highest at both, and goes from .5 to 2.0. Item 5 is lowest at both and goes from .02 to .08. Looking only at net change (difference of 1.5 vs. 0.06) obfuscates the fact that both items increase by the same factor (4). That is why we want to test relative increase against each other (or factors, if you will). Thank you for your help!

Comment: The relative increase cannot be build on a subject level because 90% of the subjects have 0 on items at time1. We currently derive the factor by (1) first averaging all items over all subjects (0+0+0+1+0+2../N), and then calculating the factor (itemx_time2/itemx_time1).